# How to initialize general context variables before testing any methods within a class with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to rspec. I am writting a test for a service class and I would like a bunch of instances to be initialized before I run in any of the describe block.
I do something like :

```
RSpec.describe MyService do
before :each do

    let(:product){create(:product)}
    let(:article_student){ create(:article, targets: [:student], vat_type: vat_type, product: product)} #target student
    let(:article_teacher){ create(:article, targets: [:teacher], vat_type: vat_type, product: product) }#target teacher
    # creer des offres
    let(:offer){create(:offer, target: :student, license_length: :m12)}
    let(:offer_special_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: true, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
    let(:offer_special_non_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: false, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
    let(:order){ create(:order, establishment_account: establis

hment_account)}
end
```

then I will have several describe block (testing the different methods in MyService and I would like in each of them to modify the previously created variables in my before :each block.
For instance :

```
  describe "#create_from_order" do
    subject{ licenses }
    context "first time worker runs" do
      order.already_went_through_license_worker = false
      order.save!
      LicenseService.new.create_from_order(@order.id)
      let(:licenses){ License.where(order_id: @order.id)}
      specify { subject.count.to eq 34 }
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).to eq 4}
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(false).to eq 30 }
end
end
```

However when I try to run my test I get that the `order` inside my `context` block is not defined...

```
undefined local variable or method `order' for #<Class:0x007fc689ddfdb8>
```

Im realising my before :each code is never entered. What is the good way to achieve this, that is initialize a bunch of instance variable general context before testing any methods within the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move your `let` statements out of the `before` block. `let` is lazily evaluated, which means the blocks you define (`let(:foo) { block }`) is only executed when `foo` is called. But by wrapping the statements in a `before` block, you are not actually calling them, so nothing will happen.

To execute the statements before each test, use `let!`. This is not lazily evaluated, and gets executed as soon as you define the statement, which is what you want in this case.

```
RSpec.describe MyService do
  let!(:product){create(:product)}
  let!(:article_student){ create(:article, targets: [:student], vat_type: vat_type, product: product)} #target student
  let!(:article_teacher){ create(:article, targets: [:teacher], vat_type: vat_type, product: product) } #target teacher
  # creer des offres
  let!(:offer){create(:offer, target: :student, license_length: :m12)}
  let!(:offer_special_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: true, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
  let!(:offer_special_non_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: false, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
  let!(:order){ create(:order, establishment_account: establishment_account)}
end
```

Now, to modify the objects, use a `before` block within the context. And make sure you are not mixing `order` and `@order`.

```
context "first time worker runs" do
  before do
    order.already_went_through_license_worker = false
    order.save!
    LicenseService.new.create_from_order(order.id)
  end

  let(:licenses){ License.where(order_id: order.id)}

  specify { subject.count.to eq 34 }
  specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).to eq 4}
  specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(false).to eq 30 }
end
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: that made it work, apparently you cannot modify the variable you create with let! after they are created... I tried to writte ```product.owner == "someone" ``` after ```let!(:product){create(:product)}``` but that throws an error : ````product` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block)````. Do you know any way to bypass that ?

Comment: Checkout this summary: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/four-phase-test, most importantly the example at the bottom of the page. That should be the preferred way to set up a test, since you can use `let(:user)` to define an object, and then modify it within the example. Another good example can be found here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications#model-specs

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you cannot interact with variables in `context` or `describe` blocks, only within an example (`it`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
RSpec.describe MyService do
  describe "#create_from_order" do
    let(:product){create(:product)}
    let(:article_student){ create(:article, targets: [:student], vat_type: vat_type, product: product)} #target student
    let(:article_teacher){ create(:article, targets: [:teacher], vat_type: vat_type, product: product) }#target teacher
    # creer des offres
    let(:offer){create(:offer, target: :student, license_length: :m12)}
    let(:offer_special_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: true, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
    let(:offer_special_non_cyclic){create(:offer_special, cyclic_amount: false, free_article_id: article_teacher.id, minimum_amount: 10, license_length: :m12)} # free article @article_teacher
    let(:order){ create(:order, establishment_account: establishment_account)}

    context "first time worker runs" do
      order.already_went_through_license_worker = false
      order.save!
      LicenseService.new.create_from_order(@order.id)
      let(:licenses){ License.where(order_id: @order.id)}
      specify { subject.count.to eq 34 }
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(true).to eq 4}
      specify { subject.pluck(:is_from_offer_special).count(false).to eq 30 }
    end
  end
end
```

Also `let` method is being run if only the objects is called. If you want it to be run no matter what, you should use `let!` method.

Hope it helps